# Exception thrown: read access violation. **pDSSearch** was nullptr

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nullpointerexception, active-directory, adsi

I'm trying to code a C++ program to print the distinguishedName of an user in active directory. The program compiles without errors, however instantly crashes on start up. I admit that I don't know c++ very well, and I believe that the problem is somewhere there.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "com_library_ldap_JNIHelper.h"
#include <iads.h>
#include <adshlp.h>
#include "activeds.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <atlbase.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
string username = "Admin10";
string password = "password#10";

wchar_t wName[20];
mbstowcs(wName, username.c_str(), username.length());

wchar_t wpwd[20];
mbstowcs(wpwd, password.c_str(), password.length());

//HRESULT hr = S_OK; // COM result variable
HRESULT hr;
ADS_SEARCH_COLUMN col;  // COL for iterations
LPWSTR szUsername = wName; // user name
LPWSTR szPassword = wpwd; // password

// Interface Pointers.
IDirectorySearch* pDSSearch=NULL;

// Initialize COM.
//CoInitialize(0);
::CoInitialize(NULL);
// Add code to securely retrieve the user name and password or
// leave both as NULL to use the default security context.

// Open a connection with server.
hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://10.0.14.74/OU=Vimal,DC=test,DC=local",
    szUsername,
    szPassword,
    ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION,
    IID_IDirectorySearch,
    (void**)&pDSSearch);

string des = "description";
string name = "Name";
string dn = "distinguishedname";
string propertycheck = "(&(objectClass=user)(cn=Admin10))";

wchar_t wdes[20];
mbstowcs(wdes, des.c_str(), des.length());
LPWSTR szDes = wdes;
wchar_t wname[20];
mbstowcs(wname, name.c_str(), name.length());
LPWSTR szName = wname;
wchar_t wdn[20];
mbstowcs(wdn, dn.c_str(), dn.length());
LPWSTR szDN = wdn;
wchar_t wpc[20];
mbstowcs(wpc, propertycheck.c_str(), propertycheck.length());
LPWSTR szPC = wpc;

LPWSTR pszAttr[] = { szDes, szName, szDN };
ADS_SEARCH_HANDLE hSearch;
DWORD dwCount = 0;
DWORD dwAttrNameSize = sizeof(pszAttr) / sizeof(LPWSTR);

// Search for all objects with the 'cn' property that start with c.
hr = pDSSearch->ExecuteSearch(szPC, pszAttr, dwAttrNameSize, &hSearch);

LPWSTR pszColumn;
while (pDSSearch->GetNextRow(hSearch) != S_ADS_NOMORE_ROWS)
{
    // Get the property.
    hr = pDSSearch->GetColumn(hSearch, szDN, &col); // want user distinguishedname

    // If this object supports this attribute, display it.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        if (col.dwADsType == ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING)
            wprintf(L"The description property:%s\r\n", col.pADsValues->CaseIgnoreString);
        pDSSearch->FreeColumn(&col);
    }
    else
        puts("description property NOT available");
    puts("------------------------------------------------");
    dwCount++;
}
pDSSearch->CloseSearchHandle(hSearch);
pDSSearch->Release();

CoUninitialize();

return 0;
}
```

Below I add the screenshot of an error displaying in visual studio:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDp8I.png)

Exception thrown: read access violation.
**pDSSearch** was nullptr.

The above is the error message I got, but I have no idea how to trace it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess would be that `ADsOpenObject` fails, you must check the `hr` before continuing your program

Comment: Why are you using those arrays instead of using `std::wstring` which is a string with wide-characters to begin with? As in `wstring des = L"description";` Then you don't need the arrays nor the `mbstowcs` calls.

Comment: @Avi Berger after I increase the of wchar_t wpwd[100]; again also I got an same error.

Comment: @ Alan Birtles - after I change the code to check whether the hr is succeed or not. I would get not succeed as the output. Can please help me to this problem, why this hr is not succeed?

Comment: Did you check what the value of `hr` is? It will tell you why it didn't succeed

Comment: @Alan Birtles - Sir it return the hr value like this -2147023570, with this I don't know how to find the solution. Can you please help me to solve this problem? Because I'm completely new to this.

Comment: try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-code-lookup-tool or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage?redirectedfrom=MSDN to lookup the error codes

Comment: @Alan Birtles - Sir my intention is to find the distinguishedName of an user. So is there any way or any concept to find this problem? The above you send the two links with that I can't figure out the solution. So please give me a guide to  solve this problem or is there any other way to solve the above error which I sent earlier? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried looking up the error code? Or even just [googling it](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22-2147023570%22+hresult)

Comment: I recommend you to read this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/adshlp/nf-adshlp-adsopenobject) and pay attention to the parameter settings.

Comment: @Yujian Yao - Now I find the solution.

Comment: @Alan Birtles - Thank you so much sir. Now I find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Now I find the solution to my problem. I would changed the datatype of username and password variable which is passed to ADsOpenObject function and some more changes... Below I add the complete code for the solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <iads.h>
#include <adshlp.h>
#include "activeds.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <atlbase.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{ 
string username = "username";
string password = "password";
string resDN="";

std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(username.begin(), username.end());
LPCWSTR lpszUserName = stemp.c_str();
std::wstring stemp1 = std::wstring(password.begin(), password.end());
LPCWSTR lpszPassword = stemp1.c_str();
ADS_SEARCH_COLUMN col;  // COL for iterations


HRESULT hr;
string uType;
string check;
bool res = false;
// Interface Pointers.
IDirectorySearch* pDSSearch = NULL;

::CoInitialize(NULL);
hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://10.0.124.714/OU=Vimal,DC=test,DC=local",
    lpszUserName,
    lpszPassword,
    ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION,
    IID_IDirectorySearch,
    (void**)&pDSSearch);
std::cout << hr;
if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    std::cout << "Not working!!!";
    return 0;
}
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    wstring des = L"description";
    wstring name = L"Name";
    wstring dn = L"distinguishedname";
    wstring propertycheck = L"(&(objectClass=user)(cn=Vimaluser1))";

    std::wstring sdes = std::wstring(des.begin(), des.end());
    LPCWSTR lpszDes = sdes.c_str();
    std::wstring sname = std::wstring(name.begin(), name.end());
    LPCWSTR lpszName = sname.c_str();
    std::wstring sdn = std::wstring(dn.begin(), dn.end());
    LPCWSTR lpszDN = sdn.c_str();
    std::wstring sprop = std::wstring(propertycheck.begin(), propertycheck.end());
    LPCWSTR lpszProp = sprop.c_str();

    LPCWSTR pszAttr[] = { lpszDes, lpszName, lpszDN };
    ADS_SEARCH_HANDLE hSearch;
    DWORD dwCount = 0;
    DWORD dwAttrNameSize = sizeof(pszAttr) / sizeof(LPCWSTR);

    hr = pDSSearch->ExecuteSearch((LPWSTR)lpszProp, (LPWSTR*)pszAttr, dwAttrNameSize, &hSearch);
    LPCWSTR pszColumn;
    while (pDSSearch->GetNextRow(hSearch) != S_ADS_NOMORE_ROWS)
    {
        // Get the property.
        hr = pDSSearch->GetColumn(hSearch, (LPWSTR)lpszDN, &col); // want user distinguishedname

        // If this object supports this attribute, display it.
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            if (col.dwADsType == ADSTYPE_DN_STRING) {
                wprintf(L"The distinguishedName property:%s\r\n", col.pADsValues->DNString);
                //resDN += col.pADsValues->DNString;
            }
            else
                std::cout << "dn not found";
            pDSSearch->FreeColumn(&col);
        }
        else
            puts("distinguishedName property NOT available");
        dwCount++;
    }

    uType = "Success";
    res = true;

    pDSSearch->CloseSearchHandle(hSearch);
    pDSSearch->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
}


if (res == false)
    uType = "Login details not found...";

std::cout << uType;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Definitely I will do it sir.